# std::thread consumes all CPUs in Qt

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, cpu, stdthread

I have a function. In my function there is a c++ thread & a Qtimer. By c++ thread I receive ARP Reply packets & by QTimer I send ARP Request packets.

The simplified structure:

```
int foo()
{
... some codes ...

    QTimer::singleShot(1000, this, SLOT(beginSending()));

    std::thread tCapture(Capture);
    tCapture.join();

    return 0;
}

void Capture()
{
   while  ( ! finishCapturing )
   {
      do sth
   }
}
```

In the `tCapture` thread I have a while loop that consumes all CPUs & the Qtimer does not work!
I use `.join()` because I want to wait for the thread to finish.
when I set `finishCapturing` flag in Qtimer slot, the thread will be finished.

The above codes don't work correctly, because the c++ thread consumes all CPUs!

what is the problem?

Thanks a lot.
Ya Ali.

Comment: maybe try to get a sleep in the while in order to let the processor do something else.

Comment: I also sugest to use .run(), and wait for a signal emited by tCapture at the end of the execution.

Comment: How do you know that the thread consumes all the CPUs?

Comment: I used Sleep(1000) but does not work!

Comment: @Ispas Claudiu  because the slot does not work!

Comment: I think your "simplified structure" is maybe a little bit too much simplified in order to understand what's the problem here. Is beginSending() the slot who set finishCapturing ? in this case, you have multiple thread accessing finishCapturing, are you safe on this ?

Comment: Yes. beginSending() is ser finishCapturing. just beginSending()!
In Capture I use it.
I think there is no problem.

Comment: "I use `.join()` because I want to wait for the thread to finish." - nothing else can happen while you're waiting, so it's no surprise that  nothing happens. Leave the thread to run, and join it once the capture is complete.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is joining the thread right after creating them, that **blocks the GUI thread and the `QTimer` and all slots on that thread**.

What you should do is emit a `signal` when capturing is done;

```
public void beginSending(){
   //do sending and capture
   finishCapturing =true;
   emit finshedCapture();
}
```

If needed you can put the body of the while in a slot and have it called repeatedly with a QTimer with a timeout of 0 (which means the slot will get called as often as possible).

then you can connect the `finshedCapture()` signal to the `stop()` slot of the QTimer

```
int foo()
{
... some codes ...

    QTimer::singleShot(1000, this, SLOT(beginSending()));

    QTimer* timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, signal(timeout()), this, slot(Capture()));
    connect(this, signal(finshedCapture()), timer, slot(stop()));
    connect(this, signal(finshedCapture()), timer, slot(deleteLater()));//cleaup when done
    timer->setTimeout(0);
    timer->setSingleShot(false);
    timer->start();
    return 0;
}

void Capture()
{
   //no while because the timer will call it as needed
   //do sth

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply & your codes. your codes is very helpful but As I said in my first post, I don't want the foo function finish before completing Capture & the slot.

Comment: then you should redesign the calling code so foo can return before the capture completes and you use signals and slots to execute the code that comes after

Comment: It`s a simplified codes. I must return the results of Capture so I need the the foo function finish after completing Capture.

Comment: @MohammadRezaRamezani and you can have the `finishedCapture` signal include the result in its parameter

Comment: foo is a member of my class. I want to create dll from this class. I need the foo fnction returns the results aftet it called, not by signal & slot.

Comment: @MohammadRezaRamezani then let foo accept a callback function that will provide the results when done

Comment: pardon me because of my simple questions. I searched about callback function but i understand noting major. may you give a simple definition of callback function & how to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more of the code, this is guess-work:

1: `Capture()` does not block, so will consume as much CPU time as the operating system gives it - which will be 100% of one CPU on a lightly loaded multi-core system.

2: `foo()` is called on the main thread. It then attempts to `join()` with the your thread - which blocks until the thread finished.  I see nothing setting `finishCapturing`, so it doesn't.

3:  The `QTimer` is dispatched through the run-loop - which is blocked.

In effect, this is deadlock of the main thread.

Comment: I said i need use .join() & said i set finishCapturing in QTimer slot to blick the thread.
I think that is not deadlock!

Comment: @MohammadRezaRamezani his(1) is correct! Add `Sleep(100);` to let cpu do something else

Comment: calling `join()` is blocking the event loop that the timer depends on for its operation.  Its irrelevant whether the thread is chomping every cycle available to it or sleeping.